# Exporting a dictionary into a text-file

Tags: python

The game is about tamaguchis, and I want the tamaguchi to remember its last size and it's 3 last actions the next time it plays. I also want the date to matter, like if you don't play with it for a week it shrinks in size. So first step I thought was to save down all the relevant data to a text file, and each time the game starts the code searchs through the text file and extracts the relevant data again! But I can't even get step 1 working :( I mean, I don't get why this doesn't work??

```
file = open("Tamaguchis.txt","w")
date = time.strftime("%c")
dictionary = {"size":tamaguchin.size,"date":date,"order":lista}
file.write(dictionary)
```

it says that it can't export dictonaries, only strings to a text file. But that's not correct is it, I thought you were supposed to be able to put dictionaries in text files? :o

If anyone also has an idea on how calculate the difference between the current date, and the date saved in the text file, that'd be much appriciated :)

Sorry if noob question, and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dictionary consists only of simple python objects, you can use `json` module to serialize it and write into a file.

```
import json
with open("Tamaguchis.txt","w") as file:
    date = time.strftime("%c")
    dictionary = {"size":tamaguchin.size,"date":date,"order":lista}
    file.write(json.dumps(dictionary))
```

The same can be then read with `loads`.

```
import json
with open("Tamaguchis.txt","r") as file:
    dictionary = json.loads(file.read())
```

If your dictionary may contain more complex objects, you can either define json serializer for them, or use `pickle` module. Note, that the latter might make it possible to invoke arbitrary code if not used properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the dict to a string:

```
file.write(str(dictionary))
```

... though you might want to use `pickle`, `json` or `yaml` for the task - reading back is easier/safer then.

Oh,, for date and time caculations you might want to check the `timedelta` module.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pickle

a = {'a':1, 'b':2}
with open('temp.txt', 'w') as writer:
    data = pickle.dumps(a)
    writer.write(data)

with open('temp.txt', 'r') as reader:
    data2= pickle.loads(reader.read())
    print data2
    print type(data2)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
<type 'dict'>
```

If you care efficiency, [ujson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson) or `cPinkle` is better.